# What is the difference between these two notations for the integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Does one implicitly mean the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral?
Let, $f \in C^{1}([a,b]).$
I know,
$$ \int_{[a,b]}f ~d\mu,$$
means the Lebesgue integral of $f$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, but what does
$$ \int_{[a,b]}f(x) ~ dx,$$
mean in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: If $\mu$ is the lebesgue measure, then $$\int f\,\mathrm d \mu=\int f(x)\mu(\mathrm d x)=\int f(x)\,\mathrm d \mu(x)=\int f(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: there is no difference, there are various notations for Lebesgue's integral

Comment: As already commented, in the context of Lebesgue integration, there's no difference. The first notation, however, could also be used in connection with other measures.  And the second notation could be used in the context of Riemann integration.